# how to make a browser application,android application and ios application in a single stretch

Tags: server, ionic-framework, hybrid

Can anyone suggest me how to make a hybrid app where i am using from as ionic and backend mongodb and server as node

running the node in server automatically stated my ionic front end page and everything works fine in the browser

but while running ionic serve --lab it is not connecting to server

i already successfully implemented the browser application using the above but while making .apk file i am not able to connect to the server

can any one suggest  a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

hi finally found the solution done the server using REST API and front end as ionic which is connecting to the REST API